# write a file in jboss directory

Tags: java, xml, jboss

I want to write in an xml file located under the conf directory of jboss.

I open it like this:

```
public void initialiserXml() {
        sxb = new SAXBuilder();

        try {
                    String fileXml= System.getProperty("jboss.server.home.dir").concat("/").concat("/conf").concat("/exempleMessage.xml");
            System.out.println("Fichier xml " +fileXml);
            document = sxb.build(fileXml);
            racine = document.getRootElement();
            System.out.println("Fichier Xml trouvé");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.err.println("Aucun fichier XML trouvé");
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
             System.err.println("Fichier XML mal construit");
        } catch (IOException e) {
             System.err.println("Impossible d ' ouvrir le fichier XML");
        }
   }
```

and after modification i write the change like this

```
public void enregistreFichier()
   {
         XMLOutputter sortie = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
         try {
            sortie.output(document, new FileOutputStream(fileXml));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             System.err.println("Fichier XML source non trouvé");
        } catch (IOException e) {
             System.err.println("Impossible d ' ecrire dans le fichier XML");
        }
   }
```

This works on my test environment, but when I test this on a production environment (Linux server), it no longer works when 
i pass on sortie.output(document, new FileOutputStream(fileXml));
(FileNotFoundException)

I don t understand , my file is found when i open it with saxbuilder , but when i write in , i have a filenotfoundexception

How to solve the problem  please?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileNotFoundException is also thrown when you don't have all needed permission's to the file. In this case you might be missing write permission from /conf/exempleMessage.xml file

You should check which user is running jboss by giving command "ps -ef | grep jboss", it gives you a list all process witch name contains string jboss. After this you change ownership of file to that user by "chown : /conf/exempleMessage.xml"

Comment: You should also remember that in Linux if you want create file (and when you write the file it can means that the new file is created)  you also need write permission to the `conf` directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Indeed , it was a problem of permission . I have given access to the file and the conf directory with chmod and chown command and now it works perfectly ! Thank you very much